OpenPyXL - InvalidFileException when trying to open file
I want to call an excel file from tk to edit it and extract data and when I execute it it gives me the following error. In this line libro = load_workbook("archivo_abierto")

openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

#Adjuntar archivo
def add():
    archivo_abierto = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Seleccione Archivo", filetypes = (("xlsx files","*.xlsx"),("All Files","*.*")))  
    print(archivo_abierto)  
    
    libro = load_workbook("archivo_abierto") 
    hoja = libro.active 
    hoja['A1'] = "5" 
    hoja['B2'] = "6" 
    libro.save(filename="archivo_abierto")

I have tried different libraries part of openpyxl but the error is always the same.

load_workbook has to take a file path as an argument. You are correctly trying to pass it the contents of the archivo_abierto variable, but to do that you cannot enclose it in quotation marks (because that makes Python evaluate it as a string instead of a variable).
def add():
    archivo_abierto = filedialog.askopenfilename( [...]
    libro = load_workbook(archivo_abierto) # <-- No quotation marks anymore

